# PYTHON, Pandas Dataframe: how to select and read only certain rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

For the purpose to be clear here is the code that works perfectly (of course I put only the beginning, the rest is not important here):

```
df = pd.read_csv(
'https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/raw/master/dati-andamento-nazionale/'
'dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.csv',
parse_dates=['data'], index_col='data') 
df.index = df.index.normalize()
ts = df[['nuovi_positivi']].dropna()
sts = ts.nuovi_positivi
```

So basically it takes some data from the online Github csv that you may find here:
[Link NAZIONALE](https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/raw/master/dati-andamento-nazionale/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.csv) and look at the "data" which is the italian for "date" and extract for every date the value nuovi_positivi and then it put it into the program.

Now I have to do the same thing with this json that you may find here
[Link Json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.json)

As you may see, now for every date there are 21 different values because Italy has 21 regions (Abruzzo Basilicata Campania and so on) but I am interested ONLY with the values of the region "Veneto", and I want to extract only the rows that contains "Veneto" under the label "denominazione_regione" to get for every day the value "nuovi_positivi".

I tried with:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati- 
json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.json' , parse_dates=['data'], index_col='data', 
index_row='Veneto') 

df.index = df.index.normalize()
ts = df[['nuovi_positivi']].dropna()
sts = ts.nuovi_positivi
```

but of course it doesn't work. How to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Try df = df[df["denominazione_regione"] == 'Veneto']

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.json',
convert_dates =['data']) 
df.index = df['data']
df.index = df.index.normalize()
df = df[df["denominazione_regione"] == 'Veneto']
ts = df[['nuovi_positivi']].dropna()
sts = ts.nuovi_positivi
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am new here and I tried to put a +1 on comment but it says: "If you have less than 15 rep points you cannot vote" :( but many thanks again

Comment: No problem, good luck :)))